# Evaluate open cell segments in a notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks

The Evaluate > EvaluateNotebook evaluates the whole notebook.

Is it possible to somehow evaluate **ONLY** the open sections of a notebook?

Answer (score 4):

This will only work if you have all open cells also grouped.
Generate, for example

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell["test3", "Section"], Cell[BoxData[\(3 - 3\)], 
              "Input"]}, Open]]}] // NotebookPut
```

Then, generate a palette like this:

```
CreatePalette[Button["Eval Open", 
   Module[{r, n = SelectedNotebook[]}, 
    SelectionMove[n, Before, Notebook]; 
     While[SelectionMove[n, Next, CellGroup]; 
       r = NotebookRead[n]; MatchQ[r, 
        Cell[CellGroupData[_, _]]], 
      If[MatchQ[r, Cell[CellGroupData[__, Open]]], 
       Print["nu"]; SelectionEvaluate[n]]]]]]
```

Then, click on the first notebook. Subsequently click on the button and be surprised.