# Open parent cell groups of selected cell

Tags: notebooks, cells

I wrote a small script for a palette, which allows me to highlight a specific cell in a notebook by using `SelectionMove[mycell, All, Cell]`. The cell is selected as expected, but sometimes this cell is part of a cell group (section, subsection etc.) which is currently closed, so the cell itself is hidden, and `SelectionMove` does not reveal it.
So far, I didn't find a way to open all parent groups of this cell programatically so that this cell will be shown... Is this possible?

Comment: You can use pattern matching like there: [33416](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33416/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select parent cell group of currently selected object in notebook `nb` with `SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup]` and then open it using `FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]`.
To open all groups containing currently selected cell you can use something like this:

```
FixedPoint[
   (
       SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup];
       If[MatchQ[NotebookRead[nb], Cell[CellGroupData[_, Closed], ___]],
           FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "OpenCloseGroup"]
       ];
       NotebookRead[nb]
   )&
   ,
   Null
]
```

It will select parent group, open it (if it's closed), return selected cell expression and repeat until returned expression is unchanged (i.e. when there's no parent `CellGroup`).

### Edit

It seems that [NotebookLocate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookLocate.html) automatically opens all groups containing located cell.

So you could just add `CellTags` to selected cell and then locate it:

```
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], CellTags -> "MyFavoriteCell"]
SetSelectedNotebook[nb]; NotebookLocate["MyFavoriteCell"]
```

It should be much faster (and cleaner) than my previous, overcomplicated method.

Comment: Thanks - does what I want, but the use of `NotebookRead` makes this slightly slow when using this function in a large notebook. I didn't find a workaround, because this seems to be the only way to find out whether or not the cell group is open...

Comment: @mjayvizzle Please look at edited version.

Comment: Thanks - that's much faster! Didn't think about the option to assign a cell tag...