# How to explicitly open or close cell group?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, undocumented

There is a `"OpenCloseGroup"` in `FrontEndTokenExecute`. It act like toggle. If the selected cell group is open, `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]` will close cell group. If the selected cell group is closed, `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]` will open cell group.

But I want a way to explicitly open or close cell group. It is not like `FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionOpenAllGroups"]` or
`FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]` which will open or close all sub cell groups in any level. I want open and close one level like the `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]` does.

**Update**

The problem is actually equivalent to seeking an efficient way to get the open status of a cell group, then we can use `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]`.
Thanks to Alexey Popkov for many information. I found currently the most reliable way is to `NotebookRead` cell data to check if it is closed or not. Here is a way

```
ClearAll[openSelectedCellGroup];
openSelectedCellGroup[nb_NotebookObject]:=Module[{},
If[MatchQ[NotebookRead[nb],Cell[CellGroupData[_,Closed]]],
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb,"OpenCloseGroup"]];
```

Though `NotebookRead` seems to be inefficient if the cell group contains large data. However, my experience is that it is still workable. **But again, there should better be a more efficient way to check the open-close state of cell group. Hope anyone knows.**

**Update 2**

Alexey Popkov found a way using `CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]`. Now we finally have an efficient tool for explicitly open and close cell groups! Like this function:

```
ClearAll[openSelectedCellGroup];
openSelectedCellGroup[nb_NotebookObject]:=Module[{},
If[CurrentValue[First@Cells[NotebookSelection[nb]],"CellGroupOpen"]===Closed,
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb,"OpenCloseGroup"]];
```

See my real applications [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261560/4742)

Comment: perhaps the tokens `"SelectionOpenAllGroups"` and `"SelectionCloseAllGroups"`?

Comment: @kglr Well, "SelectionOpenAllGroups" will open all descendant subgroups in any level, it is not the same as Open or close group which just open one level

Comment: Probably the only way is to check preliminarily whether the `CellGroup` is open or not. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102575/280) is one way that doesn't take into account that the second argument of `CellGroupData` can be a `Dynamic` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately ``Developer`CellInformation`` provides information about every cell in the selected `CellGroup`, but no information on whether the group is open or closed.

Comment: There is an undocumented Symbol [`CellBoundingBox`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133537/280) which theoretically can be used to determine whether `CellGroup` is closed or not. But I know nothing about how to work with it.

Comment: Another idea is to turn on `ShowGroupOpener` for the Notebook, and determine the current state of the Opener (but I don't know how).

Comment: Related [consideration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50771/280): `NotebookLocate` automatically opens all groups containing located cell.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you so much for so many suggestions. I tried `NotebookLocate`, it is great. But it is also bugged. It only works in the same notebook. I found if I use `NotebookLocate` to locate inner folding cells in another notebook, it can not automatically open cell group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171305/280) answer [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1) demonstrated how to attach a GroupOpener to a `CellGroup` using `FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "cellGroupOpenerInline"]`. Evaluating the latter, we can find that it is based upon `CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]` which can be used as follows:

```
Dynamic@CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]

CellPrint@Cell[
   CellGroupData[{Cell["Close me", "Subsubsection"], 
     Cell["goodbye cruel notebook", "Text"], Cell["I'll disappear too!", "Text"]}]];
cellObj = NextCell[];
```

[image: screenshot]

Now collapse the `CellGroup` by hand:

[image: screenshot2]

We see that `CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]` allows determining the current state of the `CellGroup`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't allow to set the state directly: `CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"] = Closed` doesn't work.

But there is an undocumented way to do this, which was uncovered by [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1) in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133523/280) answer:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`Value@FEPrivate`SetCellGroupOpen[cellObj, Closed]
```

Comment: `CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]` works like a magic. This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!